# IOS is there a way to access the Settings.Bundle from my ShareExtention

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Hi There I want my ShareSheet extension to have access to some user defaults.

I tried to store my defaults in the Settings.Bundle and access it from my ShareExtention using NSUserDefaults but that don't look like it is working,

ideally I would like my main app and the shareextention to use the same defaults and to be able to set the defaults using the standard Settings app.

Any ideas.

Comment: You need NSUserDefaults with suitName.

Comment: I looked at that Have you got an example and Is that Exposed in the setting app ?